# MYSQL Create vs alter query

Tags: mysql

Suppose I create a table employee and add columns to it in following manners:

**Method 1:**

```
CREATE TABLE employee (

  id INT,

  name VARCHAR(200)

)
```

**Method 2:**

```
CREATE TABLE employee (

  id INT

)

ALTER TABLE employee ADD name VARCHAR(200)
```

What is the difference between above two methods? Which one is more costly and time consuming?

Comment: If there is no data then both are same, and basically when you create a new table its pretty fast. However when you add a new column on an existing table with tons of data then it may be slower depending on the server capacity, more over if you add index along with new column then it will be more costly for an existing table having tons of data. For an empty is all the same.